# вывод данных из mysql в elastic

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch

Хочу данные из запроса в бд, вывести в elasticsearch -> для визуализации и наглядности "произошедших событий" за день/неделю и тд
Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше сделать